# Create lasting php login cookie sessions

Tags: php, session, cookies, authentication

I'm trying to make my login sessions last longer, so that people don't get logged out of my website too early. For example, making a blog post and losing it when they submit because php expired their cookie.

Ideally I'd like to give them say a 2 hour session where they won't be logged out, which will refresh every time they load the page (this code snippet below is before the header of each secure page)

This is what I am trying, but it comes up with an error for the setcookie() saying that there was a division by zero? What am I doing wrong here?

```
//How long sessions last
$hours = 2;

// php.ini setting required for session timeout.
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',$hours*60*60);
ini_set('session.gc_probability',1);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor',1);

//Set the session parameters and start session
$sessionCookieExpireTime=$hours*60*60;
session_set_cookie_params($sessionCookieExpireTime);
session_start();

// Reset the expiration time upon page load
if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()]))
{
    setcookie(session_name(), $_COOKIE[session_name()], time() + $sessionCookieExpireTime, "/");
}
```

**EDIT: Now working as the problem was non-standard quotes and apostrophes. Just in case anyone copies this code and uses it. Code above works now thanks!**

Comment: It has to be something else, because when I copy and paste that code I get no errors. I did have to replace all your quotes/apostrophe's though, as they aren't normal php quotes/apostrophe's

Comment: Please share your exact error message.

Comment: Ok that was it - I didn't realise that there were different quotes and apostrophes that could sneak in when copying snippets! Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest working in an editor that does syntax checking as you program, such as http://netbeans.org

Answer (score 1):

If you would like you could add this for when your cookie expires:

```
time()+60*60*24*30
```

This is like saying that the cookie expires in 60secs, 60mins, 24h and so on. You should also check out a tutorial on cookies here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp