# How to set PHP session to last for four hours?

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

How to make a session last for 4 hours even if the page is not accessed? I tried using
   `ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',14400);`
and 
    `ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime',  14400);`
like this:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime',  14400);
session_start();
```

but both won't work. I tried reading PHP SESSION but there's just a lot of information to take and I've tried several options already but to no good.

Edit: Now I've tried:

```
$hours = 4; //How long sessions last
$sessionCookieExpireTime=$hours*60*60;

// php.ini setting required for session timeout.
session_save_path('http://www.samplesite.com/');
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $sessionCookieExpireTime);
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 1);

session_set_cookie_params($sessionCookieExpireTime); /*Set the session parameters and start session*/
session_start();
```

then after validation:

```
setcookie(session_name(), $_COOKIE[session_name()], time() + 14400, "/");
```

It now shows that it will expire after 4 hours if I check the cookie data on my browser (not "When the browsing session ends") but if I leave the page inactive and get back to it after like an hour, it's not working as it logs me out. What is going on?

Comment: 4 Hours? So you want to say the intruder, that YES, I've kept the gates wide open for you, feel free to mess my system

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes

Comment: Use a different session handler = database. In the _gc (garbage collector) set max session time to whatever you need.

Comment: This is what the client wants and facebook's session can last this long (or longer) right? @Mr.Alien

Comment: @SandaraKwon I don't like facebook so I don't know, and educate your client and tell him the pros and cons, and am sure he will agree

Comment: or perhaps this is just ok for you ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265118/create-lasting-php-login-cookie-sessions?rq=1

Comment: @Mr.Alien How much is different 4 hours from the default of 30 minutes? If you build unsecure systems, even 1 minute is too long.

Comment: @Marek 30 mins is more secure than 4 hours imo

Comment: ahm, however long he wants it.. does somebody know how this should be done.. i edited  my question..

Answer (score -1):

Where are your session files stored? If it's shared with other applications, those other applications' session lifetime settings also apply to you. Set session.save_path to directory which only your application will use.

I would keep session.cookie_lifetime to default: until the browser is closed.

Comment: I edited the question and set the session_save_path as you've instructed but it's still not working.

Comment: Remember that you have to set the same session.gc_* settings each time before session_start.

Comment: Right . I did that but it's not working . Supposedly the default behavior of a session is that it will end only when the browser is closed right? How come it's unset after a few minutes without closing the browser?