# sessions and cookies lifetime

Tags: php, session, cookies

when we use the line session_start() there are two possibilities:
1. we are starting a new session (this method works via a cookie that the default for the expire time of it is zero, when the session ends)
2. we are continuing a current session.

in addition, if we use in one of the php files the function session_set_cookie_params($lifetime); that allows us to change the expire time of the session's cookie.

my question is if we then write in another php file before the session starts the session_set_cookie_params($lifetime); does it updates the session's cookie to expire for another $lifetime seconds?? (because usually when setting a cookie again it updates the cookie)

here are some php files that demonstrates what I'm trying to ask:

the first file:

```
<?php
$lifetime=30;
session_set_cookie_params($lifetime);

session_start();

$_SESSION["username"] = "kobe" ;

?>
```

the second file:

```
    <?php
$lifetime=30;
session_set_cookie_params($lifetime);

session_start();


echo "Username = " . $_SESSION["username"];

?>
```

after accessing the first file the session is supposed to end after 30 seconds. if I will acess the second file before the 30 seconds will it update the cookie to live for another 30 seconds?? if not can you explain why???

edit: from what I have examined I learned that the server sends a response to the browser to build the session's cookie only when the session is first initialized. now the only lifetime parameter that will be used is in the first file that the user will acess. **and from then the session will restart every lifetime seconds**?? is this right???

to demonstrate: lets say the user access the first file that says to build a session cookie that will last 30 seconds. then he aceesses the second file, the line where it says that the lifetime is 30 seconds will be ignored, the count until the session ends is from where we first accessed the first file. after that 30 seconds it will start to count another 30 seconds and then kill the session again, and then again...
is this right???

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to find out - but, with session and cookie: there are several ways to make cookie, but in your case, I am using php since it was php that you are trying to set cookie with.

Cookie is a data being stored on client-side (your computer), and it has an unique identifier where server can read/access the cookie.  No other servers can access to cookie except for the server that created the cookie.

Setting cookie tends to be implemented with three arguments:

```
setcookie(nameOfCookie, valueOfData, expire).
```

In your case, you might want to use this approach:

```
setcookie("getUsername","kobo", 30);
```

In your php script to grab the cookie:

```
 $_COOKIE["getUsername"];
```

At any time server sees there's same name of cookie, but with different data, it'll overwrite it.

Session is similar but, it get "flushed" out every time when browser is exited/closed and will have to go through the security protocol again.  Setting session data requires less argumenets, for example:

```
 $_SESSION['username'] = "Kobo";
```

and to retrive the data:

```
 echo $_SESSION['username'];
```

The catch for using session data is that you have to use `session_start();` in the beginning of the script before any of these functions could work.

Comment: no exactly. a session can be configured to work for a certain period of time, or by changing the settings in php.ini or by a script that uses the session_set_cookie_params($lifetime); function. the mechanism that the session works is by creating a cookie. I want to know if my last conclusion is right???

Comment: Regarding your comment about php.ini or session_set_cookie_params(); function - you are correct.  Yes, session protocol uses cookie mechanism for it to work.  With $lifetime=30; this cookie dies 30 seconds after cookie is first accessed, period.  But if you use this: $lifetime=time()+30; cookie is being set 30 seconds ahead from the time when cookie is first accessed.  And if the cookie is still alive by 2nd access, cookie will stay alive and will reset the cookie to new expired time (next 30 secs) and if no access within 30 secs, it dies.

Comment: I don't think youre right. from what I have checked the server sends a respond to the browser to update the cookie session only if the session is dead. the way to update the cookie session every time you access a page that continues a session is with the function set_cookie

Comment: You worded it correctly.  No need to worry about cookie if you are using session since it uses cookie mechanism and functions on its own.  I thought you wanted more of manual approach to using cookie.  Sorry.  :)  Maybe this link is what you were looking in depth. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265118/create-lasting-php-login-cookie-sessions?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

> after accessing the first file the session is supposed to end after 30 seconds. if I will acess the second file before the 30 seconds will it update the cookie to live for another 30 seconds?? if not can you explain why???

NO the expiration date won't be extended. I just had the similar problem and used edge browser which could show cookie(name,value,expiration_date)
and I found out the only way to extend the time is that after

```
$lifetime=30;
session_set_cookie_params($lifetime);
```

you call

```
setcookie(session_name(), session_id(),time() + {extended seconds})
```

edit:
I just realized this question is 10 years old.